# chart.js display time on x-axis as 24 hours

Tags: javascript, time, charts, chart.js, linechart

I have created a chart using chart.js. My data is generated in each minute. So the x-axes displays in the format HH:mm:ss(19:14:03) showing the coordinates in each minute. I want the ticks in x-axis to be in hours.
Time 19:14:03 should be displayed between the tick 19:00 and 20:00.

Here is the chart generated showing x-axes per minute. I want the axes ticks to be displayed hourly basis
[image]

Below is the code I have tried.

```js
var timedata = ["19:14:03", "19:15:03", "19:16:04", "19:17:04", "19:18:05", "19:19:05", "19:20:05"];
var chartdata = {
  labels: timeData,
  datasets: [{
    data: temp1,
    options: {
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          type: 'time',
          time: {
            format: "HH:mm:ss",
            unit: 'hour',
            unitStepSize: 1,
            displayFormats: {
              'minute': 'HH:mm',
              'hour': 'HH:mm',
              min: '00:00',
              max: '23:59'
            },
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  }]
};
```

Comment: Also looking for a solution, did you fix it?